# How can I remove particular value from query string for e.g  Default.aspx?name="my name is abc"

Tags: asp.net, query-string

How can I remove particular value from query string for e.g  Default.aspx?name="my name is abc"?

I want to remove 'abc' from above query string .

How can I do that??

I just want to show 'my name is' as a output.

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? In JavaScript on the browser, using some form of server based scripting engine like ASP or PHP; or using a CGI application?

Comment: Default.aspx hints it is ASP.

Comment: just put some simple cs code plz